# scrollTop function is not scrolling the page to top

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following JQuery which works to scroll the page to the top using animate():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('#toTop').fadeIn();   
        } else {
            $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#toTop').click(function() {
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
    });
});
```

My HTML which works to scroll the page is:

```
<div class="gototop" id="toTop"></div>
```

But the issue I am having is if I use only one then the HTML code works. If I have multiple of them, none of them works.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have multiple of them'? Do you mean having many divs with the same id? If so, remove the id (each element on page must have unique id) and just use $('.gototop').click(function() { });

Comment: Please tell me you dont copy paste the element and keep the same id.

Comment: I did without thinking, corrected now :)

Comment: lol @ mkprogramming... of course! as wise as stackoverflow is, I have to wait 9 minutes!!! but I sure will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying if you have multiple `<div class="gototop" id="toTop"></div>` it won't work ?

You should not have multiple div's with the same ID such as `id="toTop"` in your code. You could use a bunch of divs like this: `<div class="gototop"></div>` and alter your jquery to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
        $('.gototop').fadeIn();   
    } else {
        $('.gototop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.gototop').click(function() {
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s must be unique. I assume you copy and paste `<div class="gototop" id="toTop"></div>` which will then have one ID multiple times, which is an error.

Rather skip the ID attribute completely `<div class="gototop" id="toTop"></div>` and change your jQuery to: `$('.gototop').click(function()`

Comment: thanks you ... this did the trick :) Unfortunately  I can pick only ONE answer as the correct answer (but yours is just as correct as the other one)